# How to properly send a JSON array with Spring api?

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring-boot, fetch

So I'm working on building a lil website that's supposed to showcase insects and some info about em, and I've gotten the fetch call and the site itself up and running, no problem. On the back-end I have an API with a Spring Boot that retrieves my InsectObject, which for now just holds a *title* and *description* string and that works fine.

Now, excuse me as I try to explain the issue to the best of my abilities.

My problem is that I'm getting a response as follows from my API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "mantis",
        "description": "leafy boi"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "moth",
        "description": "fly boi"
    }
]
```

Wheres I want it to return it as:

```
{
bugs: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "mantis",
        "description": "leafy boi"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "moth",
        "description": "fly boi"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is how *I think*  a proper api call should look like. But then again, it's the first time I venture into this territory  and I've only been following tutorials and documentation, building my own picture along the way.

If it's of any relevance, my rest controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class BugSiteController {

    private final InsectRepository repository;

    BugSiteController(InsectRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // get all bugs from the repo
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/bugs")
    List<InsectObject> getAll() { 

        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Is it something in my getAll() method I should change to get the desired result? or should I be able to work with the first result regardless? Should I maybe return something other than a List<>? I tried with ResponseEntity but had the exact same result, just way more verbose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a class wrapper for a response like:
`class BugResponse {
private List<InsectObject> bugs;

getters/setters ..
}`
and use it as the return of `BugSiteController.getAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the value in Model or you could set it in a Map.

#### Model

```java
class InsectResponse {

  @JsonProperty("bug")
  private List<InsectObject> insectObject;
  // Getter, Setter & Constructor
}
```

#### Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/bugs")
public ReponseEntity getAll() { 
   return ResponseEntity.ok(new InsectResponse(repository.findAll()));
}
```

or

```java
@GetMapping("/bugs")
public ReponseEntity getAll() { 
   return ResponseEntity.ok(new HashMap<String, List<InsectObject>>() {{
            put("bug", repository.findAll());
        }});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using a Map worked perfectly, and it was less stuff to implement (I like keeping my codes small). May I ask what's going on in the ResponseEntity.ok() method? I haven't encountered double {{}}} brackets and I don't understand why the put() method is in there and fully functional.

Comment: I have initialized the Map anonymously, instead of creating an object and calling a put method. You could check https://javatutorial.net/java-hashmap-inline-initialization it will give you  clear understanding

Answer (score 1):

On the `InsectObject` entity class add:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "bug")
```